# Issue Report Export to Excel in RDLC Report

Tags: c#, reporting-services, report, rdlc

I have added an `RDLC` Report in my .Net Application.

Data generates in reports with Proper design.

But when I tried to export it into Excel, I get some columns Merged in more than one Cells...

How can I prevent Columns into merging cells ??

Answer (score 3):

To avoid merged cells in exported SSRS reports, you need to verify that cell alignment is Excel-friendly. This [usually can be fixed by making sure that headers and footers are aligned with the columns in the details area](http://blog.ambitionit.nl/archive/2009/07/17/extra-and-merged-columns-when-exporting-from-ssrs-to-excel.aspx). The right side of a header, footer, or other object should align with the right side of the report columns, same goes for the left.

[If you still experience issues, this MSDN blog post includes some additional workarounds.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrisbal/archive/2006/07/08/659545.aspx)