# cells merge when exporting to excel in rdlc

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, rdlc

I have an rdlc report in my application. The report looks good when seen on the web page, but when I choose the option of exporting to Excel, I get some columns merged in more than one cells. I don't want columns to be merged. How can I prevent this. I already saw this post, but the link provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747988/issue-report-export-to-excel-in-rdlc-report) post is not working.

Any help with this issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the post you shared suggested, this is usually down to cells/textboxes not aligning in your report design.

SSRS will attempt to replicate the layout that you see in the report preview (or webpage in your case). To do this it will add additional columns to provide the correct spacing and then will merge cells that cross those boundaries.

Make sure that all your textboxes align with no horizontal gap etc. For example, if your report contains a table/matrix and a textbox with a title. Make sure that the title textbox starts and finishes exactly in line with a cell in the table/matrix.

Note that cells will still be merged if they cross the boundaries of columns (e.g. the title in this example, might be merged across several columns depending on it's width).

Sticking with our title scenario, if you need to stop it from merging under any circumstances then you could try this (untested).

Create two textboxes, one wide enough to fit the title in and another that is the same width as other data that shoudl be in the same column in the final excel output. For example, if you have a table with 6 columns, the first textbox will be the same size as those 6 columns but the smaller version will be aligned with the first table column only.

Set the location of both these textboxes to the same location (so they overlap).

Then in the `hidden` property set one to be hidden when `Globals!RenderFormat = "EXCELOPENXML"` and the other when this expression is not true. This way the short textbox will only get rendered when exporting to excel, and the logn one will only get rendered to screen.

Depending on version SSRS etc you will have to decide which render format(s) to check for.

See here for documentation on RenderFormat

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/built-in-collections-built-in-globals-and-users-references-report-builder?view=sql-server-ver15